# Headless server xamarin no visual studio.Possible

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, msbuild

Is it possible to have a build server,building xamarin forms application without visual studio 2017 installed?

Basically just msbuild installed but not visual studio.

thanks

Comment: I don't think so because with Visual Studio comes Xamarin.

Comment: While the "simple" answer is no, the actual answer is yes it possible, do it all the time. macOS "headless" Xamarin build servers are easy to setup and do not require VS4M to be installed, all the Xamarin installers are separately available without VS4M. On Windows, it is more involved as a manually setup is required due to the fact that the Xamarin frameworks are .vsix based (and thus can extracted via an VS offline layout) and MSBuild 15.x can be installed via .Net Core, no Visual Studio IDE needed on a WinTel box to build Xamarin solutions and once a PS script can do the install/config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a build server,building xamarin forms application without visual studio 2017 installed?

The simple answer is no. That is because:

> We don't currently have separate, headless build tools for Xamarin
>   projects. You'll want to install Visual Studio with the Xamarin
>   components.

See the [Xamarin and Visual Studio Build Tools 2017](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95660/xamarin-and-visual-studio-build-tools-2017) for detailed info.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While the "simple" answer is no, the actual answer is yes it possible, do it all the time. macOS "headless" Xamarin build servers are easy to setup and do not require VS4M to be installed, all the Xamarin installers are separately available without VS4M. On Windows, it is more involved as a  manually setup due to the fact that the Xamarin frameworks are .vsix based (and thus can extracted via an VS offline layout) and MSBuild 15.x can be installed via .Net Core, no Visual Studio IDE needed on a WinTel box to build Xamarin solutions.

Comment: @SushiHangover where can I read a bit more about it. It would a great win I could manage to have a headless server on windows